# How to make inner div with overflow:scroll stay inside outer div?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a table within a div within another div, like this:

```
<div id="outer">
    <div class="inner">
        <h4>Search results</h4>
        <table>
            <tr><th>Internal user</th><th>External domain</th><th># in</th><th>Last in</th><th># out</th><th>Last out</th><th>Is member</th></tr>
            <tr><td>Person Name</td><td>company.com</td><td>10</td><td>20/07/2014 13:00</td><td>11</td><td>21/07/2014 11:00</td><td>No</td></tr>
            <!-- Lots more data rows -->
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

The table body is dynamically generated by javascript.
The outer div has `position:fixed`.
The inner div has `overflow:scroll`, and should always fill the outer div but never go outside its borders.

Additionally:

- If the outer div has `bottom` set to `auto`, the inner and outer divs should both expand to fit the entire table; or
- If the outer div has `bottom` set to any fixed value (e.g. "10px"), the inner div should remain within the outer.

Similar rules should apply to the width of both divs depending on whether I set the outer div `right` to either `auto` or a fixed value.

The plan is that I start with `bottom:auto` on the outer div while javascript generates the table body, so both divs expand to fit the table.
Then, after the table is complete, I compare the outer div's size to the viewport size.
If the outer div's automatic size fits in the viewport, I leave it as `auto`, otherwise I set fixed values to make it fit in the viewport, and the user can scroll to see the rest of the table.

Is there any single set of CSS rules that will achieve this, when the only properties I change in javascript are on the outer div?

The closest I've got is to set both `height:100%` and `width:100%` on the inner div. The only problem with this is that the inner div's scrollbars go a few pixels outside the outer div.

I've also tried:

- Not setting any dimensions on the inner div. This makes it always size to the table, ignoring the size of the outer div; and
- Setting `position:absolute` and left/top/right/bottom all to 0 on the inner div. This makes both divs go to zero size when the outer div's size is `auto`.

This would be simpler with only one div instead of two, but two borders of different colours provide better contrast in the web application this is designed for.

Here's a JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/jr5R2

Comment: You can add multiple borders with the `::before` and `::after` pseudo elements. See http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/multiple-borders/

Comment: @Joebot - That could be useful, except with `overflow:scroll`, the pseudo-element border appears inside the scrollbars when I want it outside.

Comment: @Joebot - Upvote for your link. I was not aware of the `outline` property, which produces exactly the look and behaviour I want.

Answer (score 7):

There need to add `height: 100%` to both outer and inner `div`

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/amoljawale/jr5R2/1/)

```
#outer {
    display: block;
    position: fixed;
    left: 1px;
    top: 40px;
    width: auto;
    right: auto;
    bottom: auto;
    z-index: 1000;
    border: 2px solid silver;
    height: 100%;
}
#outer .inner {
    background-color: white;
    border: 1px solid black;
    padding: 2px;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    height: 100%;     
}
```

Comment: That doesn't help. With `height:100%` on the outer div, it ignores the `bottom` property, and I can't make the initial size of both divs fit the table. It also makes both divs extend past the bottom of the viewport.