# How to style a div with overflow scroll inside stretched content

Tags: html, css

I would like to have a header, footer and main content inside a page that never stretches beyond the browser window.

[image: Page layout]

If the component inside the main area overflows I would like it to have a scrollbar (**EDIT**: but it should still fill the main area). I tried flexbox, grid, various trails and errors and I could not find the solution if it is even possible. When the component overflows it always stretches the main area so much it pushes the footer out ot the browser boundaries or the main area overflows beyond the footer which stays in place at the bottom of the page.

I found this question [How to make inner div with overflow:scroll stay inside outer div?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24925510), but no combination of `height: 100%` worked for me.

**EDIT:** [This](https://stackblitz.com/edit/web-platform-vwncgo?file=styles.css) is my attempt so far

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  height: 100vh;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: 3rem 1fr 3rem;
  font-family: system-ui, sans-serif;
}

header,
footer {
  background-color: lightblue;
  padding: 1rem;
  text-align: center;
}

main {
  padding: 2rem;
  text-align: center;
  height: 100%;
}

.component {
  background-color: lightblue;
  padding: 1rem;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

```html
    <header>header</header>
    <main>
      <p>main</p>
      <div class="component">
        Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Nulla similique assumenda unde doloribus velit accusantium dolores accusamus iste! Doloribus atque fuga debitis, laboriosam rerum mollitia eum dolorem facilis, officiis, modi voluptatem optio reiciendis delectus minus pariatur nam nulla vitae quasi quis tenetur alias amet eaque molestias. Doloremque ipsam sit fuga ex delectus adipisci et porro perferendis accusantium sequi. Doloribus consequuntur quas quo temporibus saepe accusamus alias porro facilis error, perspiciatis ut rem? Ullam quibusdam quod est molestias? Obcaecati, similique praesentium quaerat doloribus beatae laboriosam corrupti qui, voluptatem officiis sed repellat commodi voluptates! Eos dicta, neque numquam facilis, quidem in laboriosam accusantium expedita hic eaque ad placeat, vitae praesentium temporibus quod. Perferendis consequuntur commodi debitis repellat ullam velit, at inventore repudiandae sit illo placeat autem, corrupti quibusdam praesentium soluta rerum? Minima libero deserunt praesentium suscipit recusandae, similique inventore sunt debitis ut corrupti dolorem placeat iure nemo eos mollitia earum vero dicta illum, necessitatibus rem a? Ad nemo quod possimus cum perferendis eum dicta placeat minima corporis velit impedit incidunt libero mollitia itaque quae inventore molestias dolorum non, aspernatur eos tempore. Sed perferendis corporis eius quod nulla temporibus architecto quia minus officiis maxime! A laborum quisquam tenetur natus consequatur magnam? Totam, illo?
      </div>
    </main>
    <footer>footer</footer>
```

Comment: Could you share a stackblitz version of your code?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I included the link in the question

Answer (score 0):

To make the `.component` scrollable you need to assign `max-height` and set the `overflow: scroll` in CSS

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  height: 100vh;
}

.flex_column_center {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.card {
  background-color: #C3BEE7;
  margin: 8px 16px;
  padding: 24px;
  font-size: 16px;
  border-radius: 10px;
}

.component {
  background-color: #AAAAAA;
  padding: 16px;
  max-height: 250px;
  overflow: scroll;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <header class="card flex_column_center">
    header
  </header>
  <main class="card flex_column_center">
    main
    <div class="component flex_column_center">
      <span>.component</span>
      <img src="https://picsum.photos/500" />
    </div>
  </main>
  <footer class="card flex_column_center">
    footer
  </footer>
</body>
```

Comment: The problem is that I do not want to exactly specify the height of the component. I want it to fill the main area.

Answer (score 0):

I would use use flex on your body with flex grow for your content and then absolutely position a div inside your content that has overflow auto

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}

body {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.content {
  position: relative;
  flex-grow: 1;
}

.scroller {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: auto;
}

.padded {
  display: block;
  padding-top: 100vh;
}
```

```html
<div class="header">header</div>
<div class="content">
  <div class="scroller">
    content with scroll
    <span class="padded">padded content to show scroll - don't need this span</span>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="footer">footer</div>
```

If you need content above your component, then you can just repeat the flex pattern inside content:

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}

body {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.content {
  flex-grow: 1;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.component {
  flex-grow: 1;
  position: relative;
}

.scroller {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: auto;
}

.padded {
  display: block;
  padding-top: 100vh;
}
```

```html
<div class="header">header</div>
<div class="content">
  some content here
  <div class="component">
    <div class="scroller">
      component content
      <span class="padded">padded content to show scroll - don't need this span</span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="footer">footer</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
body {
    height: 100vh;
    margin: 0;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}

div {
    background: rgb(170, 124, 213);
    margin: 5px;
    min-height: 30px;
}

.main {
    height: auto;
    padding: 5px;
    display: flex;
    flex: 1;
    flex-direction: column;
}

.main div {
    background: red;
    padding: 20px;
    overflow-y: auto;
    flex: 1;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="header">HEADER</div>
    <div class="main">MAIN
        <div>Paste as many text here as you needd</div>
    </div>
    <div class="footer">FOOTER</div>
</body>
</html>
```